# Preposition "to" at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

Is this usage of *to* at the beginning of the sentence correct?

> **To** whom is she writing a letter all day long?

Is there another way to construct this sentence?

Answer (score 4):

There is no rule forbidding the use of a preposition at the head of a sentence. So your sentence is fine.

In conversational English, however, "whom" is not usually used in that it sounds too formal or pretentious to some speakers. We normally use "who" in place of it regardless of whether it functions as an object or as the subject of the sentence. However, "whom" is obligatory when it's preceded by a preposition. So, as an alternative, you can move the preposition and leave it *stranded* at the end of the clause.

> Who is she writing a letter to all day long?

Answer (score 0):

It's correct. You can modify it to "who is she writing a letter to all day long?"

"Whom" is used in formal English; "who", on the other hand, is usually used in informal circumstances.

Comment: I agree. But I think the OP needs more explanations. Why is it correct?

Comment: "whom" is used in formal English, well "who" is used in informal way.

Comment: You should [edit] your answer to include your explanation of why it is correct to use "To" at the beginning of the sentence. See [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1117/) for more information.

Comment: @dan I help you put that in your answer. If you don't like it, please roll it back. You can also edit it again as ColleenV said.

Comment: 'Whom' is used in informal English all the time and 'who' in formal English.

Comment: @Chenmunka I'm afraid you're wrong about the former case. The calumny heaped on that poor little objective pronoun is all out of proportion to its size. You'll find answers here that state things like **You should never use _whom_ under any circumstances unless you want to be perceived as a toffee-nose wanker.** Well, maybe not _quite_ as strong as that, but the opposition to use of the _pronoun whose name we dare not speak_, especially among USAians, is dedicated—and even a little weird, imo.

Answer (score -5):

Yes. The way you wrote that is the most grammatically correct way to write that sentence. There is nothing wrong with an infinitive at the start of a sentence.  However, a lot of English speakers will "split" the infinitive, and say,

> Whom is she writing a letter to all day long.

By rule, this is improper grammar. It leads to the sin of changing whom to who,
 (which we all do all the time. Admit it folks) because it's now at the beginning of the sentence. We all do it though, and it does sound cleaner, and at this point, it's a well-accepted part of the language by those who are not "grammar nazis." In common parlance, it's probably even how most people would say it.  If someone corrects you, feel free to tell them they're being pedantic and move along.

Comment: "To" is a preposition here. Not an infinitive marker.

Comment: Fluent speakers would not be likely to say "Whom is she writing a letter to all day long."

Comment: Read the comments! **THERE IS NO INFINITIVE IN THE SENTENCE.**